# Sysout prints unreadable characters when the java program is run on unix

Tags: java, unix

Before tagging this as duplicate, answer this question first. I have been searching and cannot resolve this with the answers from the previous related questions.

I have a Java program that prints text on the console.During my test on Eclipse, the text is readable. However, this Java program is intended to be called by a Unix job. But when I open the joblog the text is unreadable.

```
d^@^C????^D^F?`^T??Q0(????c?Z1?^
```

I tried to change my code in Java by defining the character encoding on the Sysout, but neither of the code below worked.

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "ASCII"));

System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"));
```

The joblog is on ASCII format.

```
$file myFile.txt
myFile.txt: ascii text
```

Comment: pls provide the complete code as well as text content which is getting printed incorrectly

Comment: It's just a simple System.out.println(text);

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so I'm writing an "answer". 
It could be a problem with the encoding of the JavaVM your program is running on.

You can change it by setting the encoding parameters:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dfile.io.encoding=UTF-8
-DjavaEncoding=UTF-8
```

Replace UTF-8 with the encoding you want to use.